# How to set Custom-Field type column on SharePoint Application Page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, page-layout

I have page layout for my sharepoint news. 
I have control where administrator can set few checkboxes.
How can i set that selected choices to custom field in my news item?

I got events reciever but i dont have access to my page layout controls there.
I need some event like "SaveButtonClick" or something similar...

Comment: I want to save special data to custom field.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25583/set-value-for-custom-field-type) can help you!

Comment: I have custom page layout for news. and not default sharepoint forms.

Comment: It's possible that add those codes in your application page.

Comment: yes i can write any code in my page layout codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add new hidden field to content type.
2. On page postback save your data from custom controls to hidden fields.
3. In event reciever i can use now data from my hidden fields.